# High ping when using router directly via WiFi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ping, isp

My router (after having a plan upgrade) is giving me poor connection and very high ping. My ISP is telling me that the problem isn't on their end but mine.

**If I use my own router for WiFi and piggy back it onto the Ethernet ports on the back of my ISP's router, the ping (for eg., 8.8.8.8) swings wildly from 20 ms to 8000+ ms.**

This is through pinging directly from my personal router, which I have installed DD-WRT onto and the speed test according to speedtest.net is 3.2 Mb/s download and 0.6 Mb/s upload.

**The speed test provided by google says it is 1.2 Mb/s to 0.28 Mb/s when I should be getting 10 Mb/s download and 1 Mb/s upload.**

On the other side of the coin with my personal router shut off and connected through WiFi to my ISP's router I get download speeds of 2.8 Mb/s and upload of 0.5 Mb/s to speedtest.net and slower to the Google one.

Then later, while pinging 8.8.8.8 for my router (piggy-backed), there was around 47% lost packets out of 196, and I had same situation as before from my ISP's router, which was around 63% lost out of 184 sent packets.

**Before they "Upgraded" our speeds from 6 Mb/s to 10, it ran perfectly fine for all intents and purposes with >1% lost packets around 5.8 Mb/s download and 0.3 Mb/s upload, and had a fairly stable ping of around 30-40 ms through WiFi to 8.8.8.8.**

Additionally, they gave us a new modem because they said the old one was incompatible, and of course when I tried to re-plug my old modem all of the settings were back to the default because the installer restored it to factory defaults, except now it doesn't even have the PPOE interfaces setup.

**Can someone tell me how to fix this?**

Sorry if this is too much information, I needed to explain the details.

Comment: Hi James, welcome to SuperUser.  Here people put time and effort into helping others, and your question will get more attention if you put a little more effort into asking the question.  Formatting and punctuation are important for readability, please use paragraphs etc.

Comment: What do you get if you just use their modem with something directly plugged into it with ethernet?

Comment: Your use of "piggy-backed" is a little confusing. It sounds like you have your router connected to a router provided by your ISP? And you're saying you have tried the WiFi on both? Have you tried wired on both? Does either router have an internal ping test (e.g. ping 8.8.8.8 from your router directly?) You have a lot of variables here. Try eliminating some (try wired connections to make sure it isn't the WiFi, see if router can ping, to eliminate losses elsewhere, etc)

Comment: Why do you think you should be getting 10 MB/s download and 1 MB/s upload?

Comment: my isp quotes 12 megabit(bit not byte [capital B implies byte]) down and 1.2 up, and my isp's router does not have an internal ping but my personal router does. however i do not have a computer that i can setup at the location of my dsl modem, the only computer i have that would fit is a net-book that does not have ethernet

Comment: my personal router is running DD-WRT which is a stripped down linux based firmware with more capabilities than most stock firmware